# How to create a random object by the compiler?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I created a class with 3 properties.
The class is called "Testi", between the properties there is one called "PercorsoFile".
I then created a list of "Testi", each object has the property 3.
I then create a method that takes as a parameter a random object, among all those created.
This is an example (commented):

```
private async Task<string> LetturaTestoVeloce (Testi Testoveloce)
        {
            //TestoStorageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Testoveloce[new Random().Next(1,10)].PercorsoFile);
            return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(TestoStorageFile);            
        }
```

The compiler reports error me. I do not use parenthesis [ ]
Are there any other properly?
EDIT: The error is: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type "Testi"

Comment: where `TestoStorageFile` does come from ?

Comment: Please include the exact text of the compiler error [as a edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27696840/edit)

Comment: @Tigran `StorageFile TestoStorageFile;`. EDIT: I've included the error

Answer (score 1):

the error means that you can not use `[]` to access some values in the `Testi` type.

`Testoveloce[..]` is a `Testi` type, and apparently is not a collection of any type. 
There is, by the way, possibility to enable acess via `[]`, but it depends on *what* you whant and *how* you want to do.

For example:

```
public class Testi
{
    /*special indexer property*/
    public string this[int index]
    {
        //return a path based on index
    }
}
```

here I used `C#` specific [Indexed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I had understood, but then there is another way?

Comment: I try: `public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return nuovoTesto[index]; }
        set { nuovoTesto[index] = value; }
    }
    Testi nuovoTesto = new Testi();` The new error now is: ""String" does not contain a definition for "percorsoFile" and no extension method "percorsoFile" accepting a first argument of type string could be found"